# Is the work-energy theorem only valid for conservative forces?

Tags: energy, work

I have learnt that it states "The work done on a body is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the body" which we derived by considering a position-dependent force. However, if mechanical energy is not conserved and one can do work by friction forces, one can increase the internal energy of the body. From my understanding the work-energy theorem is thus not valid unless we consider the internal energy as kinetic energy.

Is the work-energy theorem only valid for conservative, i.e. position-dependent forces?

Comment: wₑₓₜ + w (conservative) + w (non conservative) = Δκε